# Regex match for non hyphenated words

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to create a regex expression in Python for non-hyphenated words but I am unable to figure out the right syntax.

The requirements for the regex are:

1. It should not contain hyphens AND
2. It should contain atleast 1 number

The expressions that I tried are:=

> ^(?!.*-)

- This matches all non-hyphenated words but I am not able to figure out how to additionally add the second condition.

> ^(?!.*-(?=/d{1,}))

- I tried using double lookahead but I am not sure about the syntax to use for it. This matches *ID101* but also matches *STACKOVERFLOW*

Sample Words Which Should Match:
1DRIVE , ID100 , W1RELESS

Sample Words Which Should Not Match:
Basically any non-numeric string (like STACK , OVERFLOW) or any hyphenated words (Test-11 , 24-hours)

Additional Info:

I am using library **re** and compiling the regex patterns and using re.search for matching.

Any assistance would be very helpful as I am new to regex matching and am stuck on this for quite a few hours.

Comment: Is this finding multiple in one string or validating a single "word" input?

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/Kl2Qye/1) working for you?

Comment: @ctwheels It is searching in a single word after I have tokenized the input and removed the noise words.

Comment: All solutions by Toto , Paul and Emma work great for my requirement! I could choose only one as the answer. Thanks for all three of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe,

```
(?!.*-)(?=.*\d)^.+$
```

might simply work OK.

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
abc
abc1-
abc1
abc-abc1
'''

expression = r'(?m)(?!.*-)(?=.*\d)^.+$'


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['abc1']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mWq3oR/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mWq3oR/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

### RegEx 101 Explanation

```
/
(?!.*-)(?=.*\d)^.+$
/
gm

Negative Lookahead (?!.*-)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=.*\d)
Assert that the Regex below matches
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
^ asserts position at start of a line
.+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: could you explain this?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with -

`^[^-]*\d[^-]*$`

1. so we need at LEAST one digit (`\d`)
2. We need the rest of the string to contain anything BUT a - (`[^-]`)
3. We can have unlimited number of those characters, so `[^-]*`
4. but putting them together like `[^-]*\d` would fail on `aaa3-` because the - comes after a valid match- lets make sure no dashes can sneak in before or after our match `^[-]*\d$`
5. Unfortunately that means that `aaa555D` fails. So we actually need to add the first group again- `^[^-]*\d[^-]$`  --- which says start - any number of chars that aren't dashes - a digit - any number of chars that aren't dashes - end
6. Depending on style, we could also do `^([^-]*\d)+$` since the order of the digits/numbers dont matter, we can have as many of those as we want.

However, finally... this is how I would ACTUALLY solve this particular problem, since regexes may be powerful, but they tend to make the code harder to understand...

`if ("-" not in text) and re.search("\d", text):`